# Timer to poll a Delegate

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, timer

This is a followup to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13357/polling-loop-to-run-in-a-background-thread) where I was initially using a single thread and `Thread.Sleep()` to poll a delegate. I was recommended to use a timer and the `ThreadPool` to minimize resources and improve the responsiveness of `StopMonitoring()`.

This is the first time I've used the `ThreadPool` and timers in this way. I am worried about things like:

1. Infinitely running threads
2. Race Conditions
3. Firing events after `StopMonitoring()` has been called

Especially since I expect the user to call `StopMonitoring()` followed by `BeginMonitoring()` shortly after performing some actions. The only time I want the exceptions in place to be thrown are if the user has forgotten to call `StopMonitoring()` or if they have passed in a delegate which is stuck in a long-running process or infinite loop.

1. Have I correctly implemented `Timer` and `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to achieve what I want to achieve?
2. Is there any way I can have a call to `StopMonitoring()` guarantee that a subsequent call to `BeginMonitoring()` will always succeed, even if the last thread was a runaway?
3. What if a thread never becomes available on the thread pool, or is queued for an available thread while the user calls Stop and Begin again?

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

namespace FlagstoneRe.WPF.Utilities.Common
{
    /// <summary>This class allows a user to easily set up a seperate thread to poll some state,
    /// and set up an event that will fire if the state meets some condition.</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the value returned by the polling delegate.</typeparam>
    public class ConditionMonitor<T> : IDisposable
    {
        #region Private Properties
        private Object multiThreadLock = new Object();   //Prevent BeginMonitoring() race condition.
        private Dispatcher originThread = null;          //For event callbacks on the origin thread.
        private Timer nextRequest;                       //To delay between subsequent thread queuing.
        private volatile bool requestInProgress = false; //Prevent starting more than one thread.
        private volatile bool Halted = false;            //Prevent any further event callbacks.
        #endregion

        #region Delegates
        /// <summary>A delegate provided by the user of this class which returns the current state,
        /// to be tested against a certain condition in the IsConditionMet delegate.</summary>
        public delegate T RequestState();
        public RequestState RequestStateDelegate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>A delegate provided by the user of this class which determines whether given the
        /// current state, the polling program should execute the ConditionMet delegate.</summary>
        public delegate bool IsConditionMet(T state);
        public IsConditionMet IsConditionMetDelegate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>A delegate used to handle ConditionMonitor events.</summary>
        public delegate void ConditionMonitorHandler(ConditionMonitor<T> source, T state);
        /// <summary>An event which fires each time the state is polled (use sparingly).</summary>
        public event ConditionMonitorHandler RequestReceived;
        /// <summary>An event which fires when the condition is met.</summary>
        public event ConditionMonitorHandler ConditionMet;

        /// <summary>A delegate used to handle ConditionMonitor events.</summary>
        public delegate void ConditionMonitorExceptionHandler(ConditionMonitor<T> source, T state, Exception ex);
        /// <summary>An event which fires if an exception is thrown while retrieving the state
        /// or testing whether the condition is met.</summary>
        public event ConditionMonitorExceptionHandler RequestError;
        #endregion

        #region Public Properties
        /// <summary>The time between requests made to the RequestStateDelegate. Default is 1 second (1000ms)</summary>
        public double PollInterval_Milliseconds { get; set; }
        /// <summary>Set to true to automatically halt polling once the condition is met. Default is False.</summary>
        public bool HaltWhenConditionMet { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        /// <summary>Creates a new instance of a ConditionMonitor</summary>
        public ConditionMonitor()
        {
            originThread = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            PollInterval_Milliseconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds;
            HaltWhenConditionMet = false;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        /// <summary>Begins polling the RequestStateDelegate on a seperate thread.</summary>
        public void BeginMonitoring()
        {
            if( RequestStateDelegate == null ) throw new Exception("No delegate specified for polling - please set the RequestStateDelegate property.");
            lock( multiThreadLock )
            {
                if( !Halted ) throw new Exception("Previous monitoring has not yet been stopped!");
                if( requestInProgress ) throw new Exception("The previous request never completed, which means the thread is still queued, or a delegate is taking a long time to complete.");
                Halted = false;
            }
            if( nextRequest != null ) nextRequest.Dispose();
            nextRequest = new Timer(PollInterval_Milliseconds) { AutoReset = false };
            nextRequest.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(nextRequest_Elapsed);
            nextRequest.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>Halts polling and ensures that no more requests will be made or events fired.</summary>
        public void StopMonitoring()
        {
            Halted = true;
            nextRequest.Stop();
            nextRequest.Dispose();
        }

        /// <summary>Halts the thread if it is still running so that the instance can be garbage collected.</summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            StopMonitoring();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        /// <summary>Timer elapsed handler.</summary>
        private void nextRequest_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            PollState();
        }

        /// <summary>Responsible for the polling loop and invoking events back on the origin thread.</summary>
        private void PollState()
        {
            T state = default(T);
            requestInProgress = true;
            try
            {
                if( Halted ) return;
                state = RequestStateDelegate();
                InvokeEvent(RequestReceived, state);
                if( IsConditionMetDelegate != null && !Halted )
                {
                    bool bConditionMet = false;
                    bConditionMet = IsConditionMetDelegate(state);
                    if( bConditionMet )
                    {
                        InvokeEvent(ConditionMet, state);
                        if( HaltWhenConditionMet ) Halted = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                InvokeExceptionHandler(state, ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if( !Halted ) nextRequest.Start();
                requestInProgress = false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Invokes a delegate of type ConditionMonitorHandler on the origin thread.</summary>
        /// <param name="toInvoke">The delegate to invoke (RequestRecieved or ConditionMet)</param>
        /// <param name="state">The response from the last call to the RequestStateDelegate</param>
        private void InvokeEvent(ConditionMonitorHandler toInvoke, T state)
        {
            if( toInvoke != null && !Halted )
                originThread.BeginInvoke(toInvoke, new object[] { this, state });
        }
        /// <summary>Invokes the exception delegate on the origin thread.</summary>
        /// <param name="state">The response from the last call to the RequestStateDelegate, or null.</param>
        /// <param name="ex">The exception raised while calling the RequestStateDelegate or IsConditionMetDelegate.</param>
        private void InvokeExceptionHandler(T state, Exception ex)
        {
            if( RequestError != null && !Halted )
                originThread.BeginInvoke(RequestError, new object[] { this, state, ex });
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to manually queue to the thread pool from the `Elapsed` handler. It already executes on the thread pool.

Comment: Really? Wow thanks for pointing that out. It's not clear all all in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) until way down in the middle of the "Remarks" section: "If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread." I'll edit that part right now. I'll get rid of `QueueWorkItem` entirely, I don't mind if the first poll doesn't happen until `PollInterval` after `BeginMonitoring()` is called.

Comment: You should lock the entire initialization of the timer, and all changes to the `Halted` property. If `StopMonitoring` and `BeginMonitoring` are called simultaneously by two different threads, results will be unpredictable.

Comment: That's very true, although my goal is to defend against normal use, not make it idiot proof. If anyone finds themselves in a situation where two different threads are trying to manage one polling class, they're doing something horribly horribly wrong.

Comment: last version of code working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Technical**

1. I'd use `Stop` rather than `Halt` - somehow sounds more natural.
2. You should make more use of `Action` rather defining a bunch of delegate types. For instance this:

   ```
   public delegate T RequestState();
   public RequestState RequestStateDelegate { get; set; }
   ```

   Can be written as

   ```
   public Action<T> RequestState { get; set; }
   ```

   Similar for `IsConditionMet` and your various event handlers. (I'd also remove the `Delegate` suffix.)
3. `PollInterval_Milliseconds` should be a `TimeSpan`. Then you can remove the unit as part of the name and gives the caller more flexibility.
4. If you call `BeginMonitoring` in just the right moment again after it has been called before, you can have multiple `PollState()` calls going on. The right moment is that the timer just elapsed from the previous call and started to execute but hasn't set the flag yet. I don't know if you want to protect against it.
5. You will call `Dispose` twice on the timer. This should be harmless but you might add `nextRequest = null` to `StopMonitoring`.
6. This:

   ```
   nextRequest.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(nextRequest_Elapsed);
   ```

   Can be written as

   ```
   nextRequest.Elapsed += (s, e) => PollState();
   ```

   Then you can get rid of the `nextRequest_Elapsed` method.
7. I would rewrite this:

   ```
   bool bConditionMet = false;
   bConditionMet = IsConditionMetDelegate(state);
   if( bConditionMet )
   ```

   As:

   ```
   if (IsConditionMetDelegate(state))
   ```

   I don't really see any benefit into introducing the local variable.
8. Don't throw generic `Exception`. In your case I'd use `InvalidOperationException`. Using specific exceptions gives more meaning to the error and also potentially allows the caller to catch some exceptions but not others.

**Design**

As it stands your code is hard to unit test due to the async nature of the timer. Consider creating an `ITimer` interface which you can pass in with a thin wrapper implementation around the .NET `Timer`. This way you can pass in a mock implementation in unit tests which you can control as to when it executes. This is somewhat annoying but so far the only way to reliably test things like this I have found.